# Understanding how this MIPS code works

Tags: c, mips

so my professor put this problem in his slides and this was his answer, not understanding how he converted it into MIPS so if anyone could help explain this that would be great. 
Variable i is in $s3, k is in $s5, and the base address of save[] is in $s6

He gave us this C code:

```
    while( save[i] == k ) {
        i += 1;
    }
```

And gave us this MIPS code in response:

```
Loop: sll $t1, $s3, 2
      add $t1, $t1, $s6
      lw $t0, 0($t1)
      bne $t0, $s5, Exit
      addi $s3, $s3, 1
      j Loop
Exit:
```

Comment: I don't understand why he used the load word instruction though, my logic tells me (although it might be wrong) that loading the base address of $t1 into $t0 is the same as the base address of the save array?

Comment: Why should we do **your** homework? Do you have a **specific** problem?

Comment: Looks like he's trying to understand a lesson during lecture, not doing a HW problem.

Comment: Olaf, I said in the explanation "my professor gave me this problem in his slides and this was his answer." But thanks for your needed response.

Comment: @John Comment on the answer if you need further clarification or mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Loop: sll $t1, $s3, 2           # $t1 = 4*i (this is the offset to get to the ith element in your array)
      add $t1, $t1, $s6         # $t1 = 4*i + base addr of save (getting the address of save[i])
      lw $t0, 0($t1)            # $t0 = save[i] (actually loading 4B from address of save[i], so getting the actual number here)
      bne $t0, $s5, Exit        # branch to Exit if save[i] != k
      addi $s3, $s3, 1          # i++
      j Loop
Exit:
```

Things to note here:
`save` is an `int` array, so each element is 4B. That's why the offset is `4*i`.